# Why jQuery Focus function not working on second time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a effect using `focus` function in jQuery. On input focus a div is move down from top where the user can fill the data here is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/z0ucr7ec/5/) of that thing what i want now problem is it is working fine for first time the div is move down properly but when i click on that input again it is not working that time. i also used blur effect to focus out from input but after that i am not able to click on input box again. So i want to know how it'll work on second time.

Here is my jQuery code and rest is in example

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

      $( "#getcoupon" ).focus(function(){

          $("#toggle").attr('checked', true);


          $(document).keyup(function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
                $("#toggle").attr('checked', false);
                 // $("#getcoupon").focus();
            }
          }); 
      });
});
```

Comment: the code is in the example

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]."

Comment: is it fine now ? sorry for that i have not that much knowledge of this things.

Comment: actually i want to close that particular div on click escape button that is why i am using keyup function

Comment: what whole things are you trying to do i am not getting on what ground you have written this code.

Comment: Basically i want the same thing on focus which are doing on click of button on right. Like when i will click on input box the particular div will move down and on esc div will move up. Now it is working fine on first time when i do click on input box but when i click on it again after closing div it is not moving down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your code like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( "#getcoupon").focus(function(){
    $("#toggle").prop('checked', true);   
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
        $("#toggle").prop('checked', false);
        $( "#getcoupon" ).blur();
         // $("#getcoupon").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want Thanks a lot